# Power Mockito Throws "Unfinished stubbing" error when method is private, but not error when method is protected

Tags: java, mockito, private, powermock, powermockito

I am trying to test the method 'reallyCoolMethod' gets called with the correct parameters. The problem is stubbing the 'getSillyString' method is causing errors. When the method 'getSillyString' is private, the test will fail on the second doReturn:

`doReturn("superSilly").when(spy, "getSillyString", 5, false);`

however when the method is protected, the test will pass. The error is:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.UnfinishedStubbingException: 
Unfinished stubbing detected here:
-> at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.PowerMockitoCore.doAnswer(PowerMockitoCore.java:36)

E.g. thenReturn() may be missing.
Examples of correct stubbing:
    when(mock.isOk()).thenReturn(true);
    when(mock.isOk()).thenThrow(exception);
    doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
Hints:
 1. missing thenReturn()
 2. you are trying to stub a final method, you naughty developer!
```

Here is the class under test:

```
import java.util.Random;

@Singleton
public class FooBar {

  @Inject
  public FooBar(Foo foo, Bar bar) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  @POST
  @Path("foos/")
  public fooAction createFoo() {

     word1 = getSillyString(4, true);
     word2 = getSillyString(5, false);

     int id = reallyCoolMethod(word1,word2);
  }

  private String getSillyString(int size, boolean allCaps){
  }
}
```

Here is the test:

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.doReturn;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.spy;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class FooTest {

    @Test
    public void testCreateFoo() throws Exception {

      Foo foo = Mockito.mock(Foo.class);
      Bar bar = Mockito.mock(Bar.class);
      FooBar resource = new FooBar(foo, bar);
      FooBar spy = spy(resource);

      doReturn("reallySilly").when(spy, "getSillyString", 4, true);
      doReturn("superSilly").when(spy, "getSillyString", 5, false);

      doReturn(1).when(spy).reallyCoolMethod(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.anyString());
      spy.createFoo();
      verify(spy).reallyCoolMethod(Mockito.eq("reallySilly"),Mockito.Eq(superSilly));
    }

}
```

Comment: I dont know anything about powermockito I use mostly junit and mockito but that is a very weird syntax giving method name as a magic string in when token. what happens when 2 classes which implements same interface when you mock both of them they will be 2 method which maybe should act diffferent.

Comment: Why would you want to test if `reallyCoolMethod` was called anyway? Tests should be about outside behavior and not about how some result was achieved. I think you should rather test that the returned `fooAction` was created with all the right properties.

Comment: @EbuzerTahaKANAT That is specifically from the PowerMockito library, it is used to mock private methods:
https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockitousage#a-full-example-of-partial-mocking-of-a-private-method

Comment: @Pox I was trying todo TDD and write the test before I wrote that line of code

Comment: In that case you shouldn't be interested in testing that at all. TDD is all about behavior and not about implementation. If you start testing wether some private method was called you're forcing your design into a certain direction and it will be really hard to change it later. When you write a test just verify the expected result. To make the test pass you are allowed to do everything that's necessary, even copy+paste code. Once the test passes you can clean it up.

Comment: @Pox
I disagree with your comment on TDD, I think you are explaining BDD. TDD implies writing a unit test for every line of production code, and the test comes first.
Furthermore, I'm not testing whether the private method gets called, I'm simply mocking the private method and stubbing the return.
What I'm testing is that a public method gets called with the correct params, and those params come from a private method call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer here: you created hard-to-test code by putting an essential element of that class into a *private* method.

In other words: if that thing is so essential to your production code, then the better answer is to put the underlying functionality in its own class. So, you create some interface:

```
public interface SillyService {
  public String getSillyString();
}
```

And then you use dependency injection to provide "some kind" of implementation to the class that needs this service.

The desire to *mock* a private method always is a consequence of a *bad design* decision. Thus the answer does not lie within Mockito or PowerMock, but by stepping back and *improving* that design.

For starters, one can watch these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79) to learn how to write *testable* code instead.

And beyond that: please note that *PowerMock* impacts the things you can do with Mockito - as PowerMock comes with pretty much backlevel versions of Mockito. My personal recommendation: get rid of your need for PowerMock; and instead just use latest/greatest versions of Mockito.

Comment: Thanks for awesome reply! I will probably end up going with this solution.
I just found it odd that mocking the private method works once, but then throws an error when getting mocked a second time. Its like I'm missing a reset, or I need to clear the spy. Also, why would changing the method from private to protected allow the method to get mocked twice?